# NoSuchMethodException when instantiating a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class as follows:

```
public class StreamEventSuccess<T> {

    private final T event;

    public StreamEventSuccess(final T event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public T getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
}
```

I try to instiate it:

```
 StreamEventSuccess<BusinessEvent> success = new StreamEventSuccess<BusinessEvent>(event);
```

and I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ryan.protocol.StreamEventSuccess.<init>(Lcom/ryan/domain/event/BusinessEvent;)V
```

Any idea why?

the `event` parameter is of type `BusinessEvent`

Comment: Is it a runtime or compile error? The code seems fine otherwise, try to check if you don't edit wrong file or something like that.

Comment: It is runtime error, and I don't think I can be editing the wrong file :(

Comment: Have you just changed `StreamEventSuccess` to use the generic parameter while before you used `BusinessEvent` as parameter?

Comment: I just tested it and it runs fine. In the error, it says `<int>(BusnessEvent)` doesn't exist, which is true, only `<int>(Object)` exists thanks to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). However compiler should correctly call  `<int>(Object)` and not `<int>(BusnessEvent)`, try to rebuild/recompile everything again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing would happen if:

- `your-library-version-1` had a constructor `StreamEventSuccess(BusinessEvent event)`
- you have a project (or class) `project-x` that was compiled with `your-library-version-1`.
- `your-library-version-2` was made generic `StreamEventSuccess(T event)`.
- And you are running `project-x` with `your-library-version-2`.

If that's the case, just recompile the class that calls your new constructor.

That happens because the actual type of that constructor in the generic form is `<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V` so you must recompile the dependencies after generifying that class, because their bytecode is pointing to the old (non generic) version of the constructor `<init>(Lcom/ryan/domain/event/BusinessEvent;)V`

Comment: @75inchpianist I've just tested your code with intellij and it compiles and runs without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me sane. For a weird reason my shell that I was running my gradle build in didn't want to update some files. even after a clean build! I had to manually remove the build directory and restart a new shell to get it to pick up. I think that's a sign to call it a day. Thanks!